# how to match hash values in two different hashes

Tags: ruby, hash

I am trying to count the number of matching appid in two separate hashes, but my solution feels clunky. Can someone suggest a 'ruby' way of doing this?

```
#hash from an array: {"appid"=>240, "playtime_forever"=>103} {"appid"=>2670, "playtime_forever"=>1099} 
#This is Steam data for those interested

def games_in_common(friend_hash,other_hash)
    arr1=Array.new
    arr2=Array.new
    other_hash.keys.each{|k|
        arr1<<other_hash[k]
    }   

    friend_hash.keys.each{|k|
        arr2<<friend_hash[k]
    }

    return arr1 & arr2
end
```

Comment: Try to use [group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)

Comment: Why not do `arr2 = friend_hash.values` and `arr1 = other_hash.values` instead of inserting it separately by looping

Comment: It appears that `"appid"` is a key. If so, each of the two hashes (say, `h1` and `h2`) has at most one such key, meaning that your answer is zero or one: `(h1.key("appid") && h2.key("appid") && h1["appid"]==h2["appid"]) ? 1 : 0`. Somehow I don't think that's what you had in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return the values which are common in both hashes

```
 def games_in_common(friend_hash,other_hash)
    other_hash.values & friend_hash.values
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, here you go:

```
▶ h1 = [{"appid"=>240, "playtime_forever"=>103}, 
▷       {"appid"=>2670, "playtime_forever"=>1099}]
▶ h2 = [{"appid"=>240, "playtime_forever"=>103}, 
▷       {"appid"=>2671, "playtime_forever"=>1099}]
▶ h1.map { |e| e['appid'] } & h2.map { |e| e['appid'] }
#⇒ [240]
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're just trying to find if there is an `appid` in common. If this is all you're trying to do this is probably more efficient than looping through the hashes.

```
def games_in_common(friend_hash, my_hash)
  friend_hash['appid'] == my_hash['appid'] ? friend_hash['appid'] : nil
end
```